# svn (with git frontend) branch merging with different directory structure

Tags: svn, git, branch, git-svn

I have a subversion repository with a directory structure:

```
frontend
backend
  + a
  + b
```

In a other branch, someone had put the sub-folders a and b in the root directory and delete the other stuff (frontend, backend).

```
a
b
```

Now i have to merge this branch back into the trunk (backend-folder). How can I do that to dont lose the history from the branches? I use git to access and work with the subversion repository.

Comment: Just use the merge to get the changes into the backend-folder back. This won't change the history of the branches. You shouldn't do this by using git use SVN itself to do this...checkout a working copy from backend and do svn merge URL/a commit and svn merge URL/b and commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git-svn` should be able to import the history correctly considering [it uses by default](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) the `--follow-parent` option:

`--follow-parent`

> This is especially helpful when we're tracking a directory that has been moved around within the repository, or if we started tracking a branch and never tracked the trunk it was descended from.
>   This feature is enabled by default, use `--no-follow-parent` to disable it.

If that does not work, making the right change (i.e. merging that branch in order to get back the original, already imported with `git-svn`, directory structure) directly in SVN before `git-svn` it, as [khmerbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296328/khmarbaise) suggests in the comment, might be a good workaround.